# Is there a way to reference an android library that is not in the same workspace as the project?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-library

My question is simply whether i can reference an android library in eclipse and have that library in a different place than the workspace where my project is ?

Is that possible, because the link always seems to be broken if the project isn't copied in the same workspace as the project.

Comment: Add external Jar? Its a good practise to include it in your libs folder although.

Comment: I think that can be done by unchecking *copy to workspace* during import but why you need to do that?

Comment: pls take a screen shot of ur workspace and show us ?

Comment: I'm talking about adding a project that is marked as library, and i need to do that because i have multiple workspaces and all of them needs, for instnace, the compatibility library, i don't want to copy it in all my workspaces

Comment: A good way to add external Librarys OR JARs to your Android project or any Java project is:

Create a folder called libs in your project's root folder
Copy your JAR files to the libs folder
Now right click on the Jar file and then select Build Path > Add to Build Path, which will create a folder called 'Referenced Libraries' within your project

By doing this, you will not lose your libraries that are being referenced on your hard drive whenever you transfer your project to another computer.

Comment: @dsum27 i'm adding a project marked as library, not a jar

Comment: Same will apply. For example, my directory structure is C:/EclipseProjects/ <- all projects here and my reference library folder or jar files. I also like to add a baseproject here and import needed library's and Jar files and then just add baseproject to all my projects if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the library from anywhere  other than same workspace.It is posiible and it should work for all the workspaces.

It should work from anywhere from your system drive .You can import that library project into the same workspace as library project.

Comment: It only works if my library project is in the same drive as the project .. otherwise it doesn't work

Comment: It should work from anywhere from your system drive .You can import that library project into the same workspace as library project.

Comment: Select your project and go to project tab and clean your project

Comment: don't copy that import as a library project in the IDE of same workspace

Comment: Import as library? i import it like any other project, but it's marked as library